# On click get next iteration in for each loop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need when I click next button get the next div in for each loop by iteration or by data-id in pure JavaScript.

```js
var stepsWrp = document.querySelectorAll('.stepWrp');

stepsWrp.forEach(function(item, index){

 item.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON' && 
   event.target.innerText === 'Next' &&
   event.target.classList.contains('nextBtn')
   ) {    


         
  }
})
})
```

```css
.stepWrp {
display:inline-block;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.active {
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepWrp" data-id="1">
    text content 1  
    <button class="nextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="stepWrp" data-id="2">
    text content 2   
    <button class="nextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="stepWrp" data-id="3">
    text content 3 
    
</div>
```

Comment: What problem, specifically, are you having implementing this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So use [`node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) or [node.nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) to reference the element after the one that is clicked.

```js
var stepsWrp = document.querySelectorAll('.stepWrp');
stepsWrp.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(item.nextElementSibling)
  })
})
```

```css
.stepWrp {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepWrp" data-id="1">
  text content 1
  <button class="nextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="stepWrp" data-id="2">
  text content 2
  <button class="nextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="stepWrp" data-id="3">
  text content 3

</div>
```

Comment: this is working fine thanks but if it's not nextelmentsbiling is there another way to get it

Comment: Well you can read the data id, parse out the number, and add one, and select the next element with that data id

Comment: can you please give me example for how can i make it i'm sorry for more question